# dom children with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I´m trying to modify a javascript file that generates code for a gallery.

The code is

```
dom.children('div:last').append(html);
```

but I need the div has a class, I tried this but is not working.

```
dom.children('div[class="classname"]:last').append(html);
```

I can't find any information about this, any idea?

thanks

Comment: What kind of API is this? Where does `.children` and `.append` come from?

Comment: jquery picassa gallery

Comment: You didn't find any information about selectors in jQuery? Did you look at the official documentation? https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 4):

Use the standard class selector `.` just like CSS.

`dom.children('div.classname:last').append(html);`

Comment: for some reason the div dissapear with this code too, any other method?